# Progress circle duration is not like expected

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift4, duration

I want the duration of view circle progress to last exactly 1 second, but in my app, it only lasts about 0.84 seconds.

Gif:

[image]

In viewDidLoad:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let center = view.center
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
```

If you tap on the screen:

```
@objc private func handleTap() {
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1

    ///Here is defined the duration
    basicAnimation.duration = 1

    basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
}
```

I tried also with:

```
basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1)
```

But it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be lasting 1 second it is probably that it has already been running for 0.15 seconds or so before you see it. ViewDidLoad does not mean you see it. Try setting the beginTime at CACurrentMediaTime() + 2.0 and measure it again. Or run this in view did appear with a beginTime of CACurrentMediaTime().

UPDATE:
Using your code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let center = view.center
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    }


    @objc private func handleTap() {
        //prints //the time when the animation start is 30830.886492681
        print("the time when the animation start is \(CACurrentMediaTime())")
        CATransaction.begin()
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1
        ///Here is defined the duration
        basicAnimation.duration = 1
        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        //here i make sure it starts at the current time
        basicAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            //prints the current Time is 30831.895261542
            print("the current Time is \(CACurrentMediaTime())")
        }
        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }


}
```

In my example it lasted a millisecond more although my bet is that is a frame difference when the animations actually started.  Please log yours as opposed to using a video and see if it is is lasting the time it is supposed to last.  If not what other code are we missing.  Do you have something else that could be blocking the main thread?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant about beginTime at CACurrentMediaTime() + 2.0.

Comment: `beginTime` is a property declared at `CAMediaTiming` protocol, you can set it for your `basicAnimation` object as it conforms to the protocol. The suggested value is current time + 2 seconds for you to be able to see and visually validate the control when animation is started at more clear moment of time (2 seconds should be enough unless you load the view long before you display it).

Comment: as A-Live says animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.1. This will act as a delay although it has other uses.  Just know that viewDidLoad does not mean it is on screen so the layer might be animating before you see it.  It makes more sense to do this in viewDidAppear probably for what you are doing and just set the beginTime to CACurrentMediaTime() which is basically like screen time 0 for what you are seeing.

Comment: Then you mean that I have to move the code in viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear? And reverse basicAnimation.duration = 1 to basicAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.1?

Comment: Yes move code for what I think you are trying to do. In viewdidAppear no need to delay so just CACurrentMediaTime as the beginTime.

Comment: But the problem is when I tap on the screen the duration of view circle progress doesn't last exactly 1 second, I don't think it is about the delay.

Comment: Updated code to log the actual time. If there is a difference for you then there may be code we are not seeing.